# comparing the instance of a class

Tags: java, object

I create 2 objects from a class.

```
maDrive = new MaxonDrive(maDriveConnection);
liftDrive = new MaxonDrive(liftDriveConnection);
```

In this class I have a method, which I want to use for both instances but with different (sub)functionality. How can I solve this problem?

Following a made up "solution" I could think of, but doesn't seem useful or possible.

```
    public MaxonDrive(MaxonDriveConnectionIfc maxonIfc)
    {
        public void updateMotorState()
        {
            doSomething();
            if(objectOf(MaxonDrive) == maDrive){}
            else if(objectOf(MaxonDrive) == liftDrive){}
        }
    }
```

Is there a possibility to check which object is using this method to react accordingly.

Comment: Are you lookking for `instanceof` operator?

Comment: @Amongalen No. I checked `instanceof`, I'm looking for the opposite of that. Checking the object of a class and not the class of an object.

Comment: Perhaps those objects should have some property/field that let's you differentiate between them.

Comment: I think that if you [edit] your question and post a [mcve] then you will have a better chance of getting an answer that you can use to solve your issue. Just indicate in the code, via comments (or even pseudo-code), what you want the code to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AC_ As @Amongalen said since the objects are of the same class, it might be helpful to have property of the object defined and based on that property u can decide the difference in behavior.    You can have a parameterized constructor which takes the a parameter sufficient enough to differentiate objects.

```
    public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Sample s = new Sample("obj1");
        //Sample s = new Sample("obj2");
        if(s.getAttribute1().equals("obj1")){
            s.setAttribute2("This is obj1");
        }else{
            s.setAttribute2("This is obj2");
        }

        System.out.println(s.getAttribute2());

     }
}

class Sample{
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;

    Sample(String name){
        attribute1 = name;
    }

    public String getAttribute1(){
        return attribute1;
    }

    public void setAttribute2(String someValue){
        attribute2 = someValue;
    }


    public String getAttribute2(){
        return attribute2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I now also asked a collegue, and found I think the optimal solution. 
He suggested I make the class `MaxonDrive` abstract. Then create two seperate classes which extend this abstract class.

`public class LiftMaxonDrive extends MaxonDrive
{
public LiftMaxonDrive(MaxonDriveConnectionIfc maxonIfc)
    {
    super(maxonIfc);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMotorState()
    {}
}`

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is an interface, then make the 2 classes implement it with their own implementation, so they will do on their own.

like this:

```
interface GeneralizedFoo {
    String yourOwnValue();
}

class Bar implements GeneralizedFoo{

    @Override
    public String yourOwnValue() {
        return "from Bar";
    }
}

class Foo implements GeneralizedFoo {

    @Override
    public String yourOwnValue() {
        return "from Foo";
    }
}
```

Then in main:

```
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Bar bar = new Bar();

        System.out.println(foo.yourOwnValue());
        System.out.println(bar.yourOwnValue());
```

result is:

```
from Foo
from Bar
```

But what you are directly asking for is to use `instanceof` which checks the instance of the class you are using: https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_instanceof.asp

that would be somewhere similar as:

```
        if(foo instanceof Foo) {
            System.out.println("from Foo");
        } else {
            System.out.println("from Bar");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I ran across ´instanceof´, but I am in the class Foo and want to check the object there. I know that it is an instance of the class Foo. As far as I understand, the 'instanceof' does not help me.
Making an interface for just the one function seems like an overkill. 
It seems to me, that I have to write two functions that are very similar, as there is no possibility to check the object in the class?!

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope it helps you, note that checking instanceof is quite error prone, I would do it in exceptional situation, there is nothing wrong to have small interfaces, much better in OOP to have many small specific rather than a big one

Comment: @LéoSchneider I think that in case of OP both `object1` and `object2` are of the same type and he wants different behaviour for each of them. This can be solved based on some object property.